# add page to the bottom of last page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, transition, single-page-application

i'm trying to figure out how i can append a page to the bottom of another page after clicking on a button.

Usually the page with the button disappears and the next page is loaded.
I don't want the first page to disappear, instead just add the content of the second page at the bottom.

For example i have this structure of a page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
    <div  data-role="header"><h1>Header Page 1</h1></div>
    <div  data-role="content">
        If you click this button, this page will be hidden and the next page will slide up.
        <a href="#p2" data-role="button" data-transition="slideup">Go To Page 2</a>
    </div>
</div> 
<div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <div  data-role="header" data-rel="back"><h1>Header Page 2</h1></div> 
    <div  data-role="content">
        <p>This is page2</p>
        <a href="#p3" data-role="button" data-transition="slideup">Go To Page 3</a>        
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="p3">
    <div  data-role="header" data-rel="back"><h1>Header Page 3</h1></div>
    <div  data-role="content">
        <p>This is page3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TDg9/T6UHV/) for illustration.

Comment: you want to copy contents of next page into current page, without showing that next page?

Comment: not just some content, the whole page should be added at the bottom of the current page

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't get what you want. What do you mean by "_page should be added at the bottom of the current page_"? You mean merging both pages?

Comment: do you mean, including the header and footer + the content. or just the content of the previous page? is the page you are trying to inject to the new page static or dynamic?

Comment: well let me explain it with the code example i posted above: if you open it in jsfiddle, you will see just the content of the first page with the id="p1". If you click the button on this page, p1 will disappear and the page with id="p2" will slide up. Instead of disapearing of content of p1, i want to merge content of p1 + p2